# If I have a tree in Java, and I set the root to NULL, will all of the nodes be garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Most tree delete operations in Java go about setting each child to NULL so each node is garbage collected. Shouldn't simply setting the root to NULL work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, any object that cannot be reached by any live thread will be eligible for garbage collection, even if this you have a huge graph of objects that still reference each other (like a tree) but aren't reachable by any thread.

That said, setting the child references to null would not do anything for eligibility since if there is no reference to the root but there are still references to a node at least that node cannot be gc'd.

Depending on how the tree is set up setting every node reference to null might allow a huge part of the tree be collected, even if a node is still held elsewhere (not necessarily in *your* code).

Example:

Consider a linked list (degenerated tree) like this:

```
your code -> root <-> node1 <-> node2 <-> node3 <- some other code
```

If you set the reference to `root` to null in your code, the list still cannot be collected since there's some other code referencing `node3` which in turn references the other nodes up to `root`.

However, if you remove references between the nodes as well, `root`, `node1` and `node2` can be collected - while `node3` cannot. 
(In this case it would be sufficient to remove the reference from your code to `root` and from `node3` to `node2`, but general code doesn't know which other nodes might still be referenced, so removing all tree-internal references is the safe way to go.)

Comment: Setting all the child pointers to NULL, is costly in both CPU time, and may fill up the CPU cache with useless items.   I have never come across people doing it in C#, so there must have been a something in the “java world” that often hold onto notes for a long time.

Comment: Or was it often the case that the “root” was in a very old GC generation, but most nodes in a recent generation for an important benchmark.

Comment: @IanRingrose well, in the Java world you'd not worry that much about CPU caches. Besides that in a generic tree there might be a lot of data associated to the nodes so allowing the garbage collector to free that data would help in terms of memory. As always it's a speed <-> memory tradeoff.